# Private torrent over LAN

Tags: bittorrent

If you create a private torrent, is it actually possible to share it via LAN? I've tried to do it a number of times and failed.

Even adding the internal IP of the peer manually doesn't start the file transfer.

Comment: Don't you lose the distributed nature of torrents in a LAN environment, where you could just use a simple file share?

Comment: BT is way more resilient at resuming stopped downloads, but I don't see why that would even be a problem in a LAN environment, so I agree with this ^^^

Comment: Let's say I need to share large files with multiple clients in my LAN, for example during a LAN party. Torrent beats filesharing hands down. I was just wondering why a private torrent over LAN doesn't work.